# what is really in my clipboard? how does it interact with webpage?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

When I copy some content in a webpage, what will really happen? What will be saved in my clipboard buffer?

I once thought it's plant text, however, I can paste it's style or images in `M$ Word` or some web WYSIWYG editors such as `TinyMCE`. And it isn't html code, otherwise I will see tags in `gedit` or `Notepad`.

My main questions are:

1. where are the document which explains the knowledge about clipboard?
2. When I make webpages, is it possible to control what users will copy into clipboard with javascript?

Comment: I hope some javascript monster can lead us the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Background

In Windows, there is a plain text clipboard and a MIME-aware clipboard; when you copy, you'll get the plain text version *and* the rich HTML. Text editors like Notepad will just take from the plain buffer, whereas a program like Word will look in the MIME section and try to do clever stuff with the HTML it finds there.

GUI toolkits in other OSs probably do similar things.

#### Your questions

> 1. Where are the documents which explain the Windows clipboard?

I don't know.

> 2. When I make webpages, is it possible to control what users will copy into clipboard with javascript?

Not really; the GUI and the browser are responsible for what the "clipboard" even means.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows (and I'm guessing some or most other OS's), the clipboard can hold data in multiple formats. In Word, for instance, when you copy text to the clipboard, both plain text and formatted text are copied there. You can use various clipboard functions to see what formats the data is available in. A plain text editor like Notepad will use the plain text if available; an editor that understands formatted text will use that instead. So the browser copies both plain and HTML text to the clipboard, and then the program pulling from the clipboard when you paste will choose the best format to use.

> where are the document which explains the knowledge about clipboard?

For Windows (just to get an idea conceptually of how this stuff works on a mature OS), you can get a fair bit of information about this by kicking around the docs for the [.Net `Clipboard` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25w5tzxb.aspx) and its associated interfaces, like [`IDataObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idataobject.aspx).

For browsers and JavaScript, there is no current standard. There is a [proposed one](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/), but nothing widely supported yet.

> When I make webpages, is it possible to control what users will copy into clipboard with javascript?

Not that I'm aware of (except the above proposed API), not using just JavaScript; the browser does what it thinks best (usually copying both plain and formatted text).

Answer (score 2):

Currently there isn't a method to interact with a user clipboard using JUST Javascript (there is a working draft out there - see http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/).

However you can take control over it using ZeroClipboard for example (uses Flash and a Javascript interface). See http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Comment: +1 for mentioning ZeroClipboard, I should have done that (even if I do have issues with Flash).

Answer (score 0):

**You do** (sort of) copy the html.

Its just that different programs interpret the clipboard differently.

Same thing as if you copy an html table and paste it into excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an artical on Copying and Pasting in JavaScript. You could intercept the event and add your own text to control the output, but like @Neal said it also depends on whos consuming this information.

http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/1906-JavaScript-s-Copy-and-Paste-Events

http://help.dottoro.com/ljwexqxl.php